# ReferenceError: displayBoxes is not defined

Tags: laravel-5.8

How to display checkboxes where select option = category_id.

I tried for show the checkboxes , after I select a option.

And I want the same thing. But with Laravel and the database

Inspector in firefox

[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFozD.png)

**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('computers.store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="select" name="category_id" class="form-control" onchange="displayBoxes()">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option data-description="{{ $category->description }}" value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p id="description"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-none box17">
        <p></p>
        @foreach ($computers->where('category_id', 2) as $computer)
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $computer->latin }}">
            <label for="{{ $computer->latin }}">{{ $computer->name }}</label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-none box18">
        <p></p>
        @foreach ($computers->where('category_id', 3) as $computer)
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $computer->latin }}">
            <label for="{{ $computer->latin }}">{{ $computer->name }}</label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-none box19">
        <p></p>
        @foreach ($computers->where('category_id', 4) as $computer)
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $computer->latin }}">
            <label for="{{ $computer->latin }}">{{ $computer->name }}</label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">ادامه</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
    function displayBoxes() {
        let option = document.querySelector('#select');
        let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div');
        boxes.forEach(function(el) {
            el.classList.add('d-none');
        });
        document.querySelector('.box' + option.options[option.selectedIndex].value).classList.remove('.d-none');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `onchange="displayBoxes()"` from the `select` element, and 
add an `eventListener` that listen to the `change` event of this element in your `script.js` file. Your code should looks like this:

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#select');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    boxes.forEach(function(e) {
        e.classList.add('d-none');
    });
});
document.querySelector('.box' + selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value).classList.remove('.d-none');
```

Check [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/) for more info.
Also [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) to read about `eventListener`.

Comment: I tried it but my problem did not solve yet I get this error in console : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJUaP.png

Comment: Look at my answer again. I have used `selectElement` instead of your `option` as var name, but missed to change in your last line of code

Comment: Ok, just swap `option` with `selectElement`, and it should works. Look at the last line of code in my answer.

Comment: When I run this page. Returns a blank page & white page for me. and get an error in the console.

[blank page][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju50x.png